# Navigation tabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My tab is not working . here's the codes that I got from W3 Schools

https://jsfiddle.net/mobi35/uwLp87ye/

Help me I'm kinda confuse

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
   <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
   <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>
   <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
 </div>

 <div id="London" class="city">
   <h2>London</h2>
   <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="Paris" class="city" style="display:none">
   <h2>Paris</h2>
   <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="Tokyo" class="city" style="display:none">
   <h2>Tokyo</h2>
   <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
 </div>


 function openCity(cityName) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
 }
```

I'd tried doing all of the methods in W3 Schools but none of it works on my end. Can you guys help me explain my mistakes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript panel in your JSFiddle is set to run "onDomready", which would normally be fine - but because you're binding JS functions inline in your HTML using `onclick` attributes, and the function doesn't exist in JS yet, it's erroring out. Check your browser console and you'll see.

So it's essentially an order of operations issue. The code works fine in a Stack Overflow snippet, and you could set the JS load type on JSFiddle to "no wrap" to fix it as well.

In the future, you should learn how to bind `click` event handlers in JavaScript though, rather than inline HTML.

```js
function openCity(cityName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, though that's using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug as pointed by [Jon Uleis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334839/7907835)

<strike>That's a bug with jsFiddle, nothing wrong with your code.</strike>

It's working on codepen.io: https://codepen.io/LucasPaganini/pen/XeKpZR

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

### JS

```
function openCity (cityName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}
```